# Algorithms for determining nilpotence of a Real matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there an (efficient?) general algorithm for determining whether a matrix is nilpotent vs. non-nilpotent? Can matrixes cycle through the same non-zero matrices over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you explicitly know a matrix $A=[a_{i,j}]\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Then you calculate $\det(xI_n-A)$, a polynomial $P$ in $x$ of degree $n$. Then $P(x)=x^n$ iff $A$ is nilpotent. The calculation needs $O(n^3)$ algebraic operations $+,\times$.

There is a fly in the ointment when the $(a_{i,j})$ are great numbers. For example if $A\in M_{10}(\mathbb{Z})$ has its entries in $(-10^{10},10^{10})$, then its determinant may be $>10^{100}$. Thus we need a computer which can provide many significant digits.

About the second question, consider $e^{\frac{2i\pi}{k}}I_n$